How can I improve this answer to an HTTP spec question?
I received a downvote to this answer to a question about the HTTP spec that I don't understand. Given that my answer is directly copied from the spec, the only reasons I could think for the downvote were:

I shouldn't have used the current spec instead of the spec at the time of posting
I didn't add enough context to my answer. (Originally it was just the status codes and links to the spec without including quotes.)
It's not clear how my answer is more comprehensive than the accepted answer, and therefore looks like a shameless copy
I somehow misunderstood the question. (Maybe they asked an XY-question.)

Is there something I could do differently to improve my answer?
.

It's a single downvote. Honestly, we can't tell you why that vote was cast, as we don't (can't) know. I wouldn't worry about that too much. Writing a Meta question about a single downvote is too much, though...

The post got a single downvote. Maybe the post didn't get enough views, so appreciating users didn't get a chance to upvote it. You can try posting a bounty, maybe with additional attention the answer will get more votes of the appropriate kind.

It's a late answer to an old, not so great question, it's pretty badly formatted (why the giant header links?) and it is pretty much all quote. I wouldn't upvote or downvote it myself but it is written to draw out the people who vote based on what they see rather than what they comprehend.

What does your answer add over the previous one? Seeing it really just makes me more confused - Why don't you list 4xx and 5xx codes as optionally empty? What was different before 2024-03-31?

@MisterMiyagi The accepted answer doesn't include 304. My answer lists every single status that must not contain content. I didn't list statuses that are optionally empty because every single status can optionally have no body. I don't know what the difference with the old specs are, but I do know that the spec has changed 4 times and it could easily change again, which is why I added a date to my answer

@Gimby The giant header links were to make the statuses stand out from the quotes. I was trying to make it easy to tell at a glance, the exact statuses that required no content without needing to read the quotes. Originally they were just regular sized links, but I thought that adding the quotes might improve the answer. I'm not sure if the quotes add or detract at this point.

"every single status can optionally have no body" (assuming that's accurate) would be a good thing to include in an answer.

Despite the previous voting, I don't think it's a very good question, and I added my feedback to that effect.

Anyway, I wish we'd collectively cut it out with the "it's a single downvote" meme on Meta, and appreciate the fact that a few people actually go out of their way to try to learn how to improve their content.

I have updated my answer in response to feedback:

Improved formatting (Thanks @Gimby)
Removed quotes
Clarified how my answer is more comprehensive than the accepted answer (Thanks @MisterMiyagi)
Removed the arbitrary date (@MisterMiyagi)
Clarified that the body is always optional (Thanks @Ryan M)


I didn't say to remove quotes, I said the problem was that it was pretty much only quotes (from other sources). Answers are generally expected to be yours, not someone else's.

@Gimby Sorry for misrepresenting you. I have updated the answer. Originally, I edited my question with the update that I have changed the original answer, but that got deleted. I wanted to add somewhere that I have updated the original answer based on feedback, so I made it an answer to this question. I don't think a comment would have been prominent enough and I think that the context that the question is referring to something that has since been edited is important to have somewhere.
